# How to render a component in React according to a selected value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering, use-effect

This is my App.js which consists of a dropdown menu.

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Barchart from './Barchart'
import './barStyle.css';
const App=()=>{
  const[selects,setSelects]=useState(1); 
   function handleChange(e)
   {
     //console.log('clicked');
     const tmp=e.target.value
 // console.log(tmp);
    setSelects(e.target.value);
   }
  // let i=1;
   //const option_map=[Array(6).fill( <option>{i}</option>)];
  
    return (    
      <div >  
       <select value={selects} onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e)}>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
       <option>4</option>
       <option>5</option>
       </select> 
       <Barchart selected_val={selects}></Barchart>
       </div> 
            
     );
   }

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is my component where I am passing the value of {selects} through props.

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import './barStyle.css';

const Barchart=(props)=>{    
  const sel=props.selected_val;
  console.log(sel);
  const arrayGantt=[Array(sel).fill(<div className='gantt1'></div>)]; 
       
        return (<div>
            <div className='gantt_container'>
            <div className='gantt_main'>
            {arrayGantt.map((num)=>num)}
        </div>
            </div>
            </div>);
    }

export default Barchart;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I want Array(sel).fill to have the value of {Selects} so that it may render accordingly. Can anyone tell me how to do it with useEffect?

[What is the issue. Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7HRK.png)

[What I want to happen. Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOIxG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable in the `useEffect` dependency array to render a function if the value changes in the variable.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import './barStyle.css';

const Barchart=(props)=>{   
  const {selected_val} = props; 
  const [arrayGantt, setArrayGantt] = useState([]); 

  useEffect(()=>{
    setArrayGantt([Array(selected_val).fill(<div className='gantt1'></div>)])
  }, [selected_val]);
  console.log(selected_val);
      
        return (<div>
            <div className='gantt_container'>
            <div className='gantt_main'>
            {arrayGantt.map((num)=>num)}
        </div>
            </div>
            </div>);
    }

export default Barchart;
```

Comment: Tried doing this but Nothing is happening. WHen I tried to console log selected_val . It's consoling logging twice.

Comment: I am attaching a screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7HRK.png
Please help me out